# Love2d. States system won't load the game state a second time

Tags: lua, love2d

I'm just learning lua and love2d and I am trying to make an example game to get familiar. I'm following goature's tutorial on youtube and am using his states system to navigate the game. I finished writing the example code for the menu and decided I would like to be able to get back to the menu from the game. The problem is that the game will not load the game state a second time and instead gives me a gray screen. This should be the relavant code.

From the root file main.lua

```
function clearLoveCallbacks()
    love.draw = nil
    love.joystickpressed = nil
    love.joystickreleased = nil
    love.keypressed = nil
    love.keyrelease = nil
    love.load = nil
    love.mousepressed = nil
    love.mousereleased = nil
    love.update = nil
end

states = {}
function loadState(name)
    states = {}
    clearLoveCallbacks()
    local path = "states/" .. name
    require(path .. "/main")
    load()
end

function load()
end

function love.load()
    loadState("menu")

end
```

From the menu main.lua

```
function load()

    love.graphics.setBackgroundColor(190, 190, 190, 255)

    imgPlay = love.graphics.newImage("Textures/start.png")
    imgPlayOn = love.graphics.newImage("Textures/start_on.png")
    imgexit = love.graphics.newImage("Textures/exit.png")
    imgexitOn = love.graphics.newImage("Textures/exit_on.png")

    buttons = {
              {imgOff = imgPlay, imgOn = imgPlayOn, x = 400, y = 300 - 64, w = 256, h = 64, action = "play"},
              {imgOff = imgexit, imgOn = imgexitOn, x = 400, y = 300 + 64, w = 256, h = 64, action ="exit"}
              }
end
function love.mousepressed(x, y, button)
    if button == 1 then
        for k,v in pairs(buttons) do
            local ins = insideBox(x, y, v.x - (v.w/2), v.y - (v.h/2), v.w, v.h) -- must use v. for the rest of the arguments except the first 2 because that x and y defined in arguments of the function

            if ins then
                if v.action == "play" then
                    loadState("New_Game") -- loads new game for some reason if i load the menu state from game it won't load the game a secound time
                elseif v.action == "exit" then
                    love.event.quit() -- love2d function to quit
                end
            end
        end
    end
end
```

And from the New_Game main.lua

```
function load()
    require("States/New_Game/entities")
    love.graphics.setBackgroundColor(255,255,255,255)
    ents.startup()
    --local newEnt= ents.Create("new_ent", 128, 128)
    ents.Create("enemy_base", -math.random(128, 256), 128)
end
function love.keypressed(key, unicode)
    if love.keyboard.isDown("escape") then
        loadState("Menu")
    end
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code you have provided, as written, cannot do what you seem to want.

You seem to want to be able to call `loadState`, and you want this function to load things into globals that effectively sets up a new "state".

Well, that might be fine... except that you are using `require` to do the loading. And, unless Love2D changed how the function works, `require` will only ever load a particular script *once*.

See, it is the execution of the script itself that is changing the state. It's defining a global `load` function, which you call. It defines some other functions in the `love` table. And so forth.

But this will only happen when the script is loaded and executed. And as previously said, `require` will only do this the *first time* you require a new module.

Presumably, what you want is `dofile`, not `require`. But honestly, I'd suggest re-architecting your system to not rely on globals. Register which states you want up-front, but don't have them set global values. Instead, have each state define a table that contains its `load` function. And the `load` function should register its Love2D callbacks.

Your "states" would look more like this:

```
local ret = {}

--Executed only once.
local imgPlay = love.graphics.newImage("Textures/start.png")
local imgPlayOn = love.graphics.newImage("Textures/start_on.png")
local imgexit = love.graphics.newImage("Textures/exit.png")
local imgexitOn = love.graphics.newImage("Textures/exit_on.png")

local buttons =
{
    {imgOff = imgPlay, imgOn = imgPlayOn, x = 400, y = 300 - 64, w = 256, h = 64, action = "play"},
    {imgOff = imgexit, imgOn = imgexitOn, x = 400, y = 300 + 64, w = 256, h = 64, action ="exit"}
}

local function mousepressed(x, y, button)
    if button == 1 then
        for k,v in pairs(buttons) do
            local ins = insideBox(x, y, v.x - (v.w/2), v.y - (v.h/2), v.w, v.h) -- must use v. for the rest of the arguments except the first 2 because that x and y defined in arguments of the function

            if ins then
                if v.action == "play" then
                    loadState("New_Game") -- loads new game for some reason if i load the menu state from game it won't load the game a secound time
                elseif v.action == "exit" then
                    love.event.quit() -- love2d function to quit
                end
            end
        end
    end
end

function ret.load()
    --Actual state setup.
    love.mousepressed = mousepressed

    love.graphics.setBackgroundColor(190, 190, 190, 255)
end

return ret
```

Your `loadState` function also needs to change:

```
function loadState(name)
    states = {}
    clearLoveCallbacks()
    local path = "states/" .. name
    local state = require(path .. "/main")
    state.load()
end
```

Oh, and I would advise you to ditch whatever tutorial you are "learning" from. It's teaching you terrible things. It involves *way* too much global usage, which is what led to this problem. If you're just learning Lua, then you are learning to use Lua very badly.

Comment: Thanks this helps but what would a table like the one you are talking about look like? And do you know of any good lua tutorials?

Comment: @Jacques: I've added an example.